# Read file and add to array char

Tags: c++, file, fstream

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<cctype>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    ifstream fin;
    int i,size,j=8,t=0;
    char kunci[21]="TFFTFFTTTTFFTFTFTFTT";
    string data;
    fin.open("datajawaban.txt");
    //getline(fin,data);
    char jawab[31];
    cout <<"ini isi file " <<data<<endl;
    for(i=0;i<=31;i++){
       fin >> jawab[i];
       jawab[31] = '/0';
       if(jawab[j]==kunci[i])t++;
       cout <<"data ke "<<i <<" "<< jawab[j] << " - " <<kunci[i]<<endl;     
       j++;
    }
    cout << "jumlah benar "<< t;
    fin.close();   
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

that is my code

the output is 
±

±
`
(
v

☺

p
 ↨
 v

P
 ☺
 v

-

0
 \
 ±
 C

P
 ☺
 v

it's wrong output, what wrong with my Code ?

please help me this time, It's my homework

Comment: Things that are immediately, obviously wrong: 1. formatting, 2. `abusing namespace std;`, 3. non-English variable names and instructions for the user.

Answer (score 3):

`jawab[31] = '/0';`  is [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behaviour) as array size is 31, array index starts with 0 and maximum index value can be size - 1 that is 30 for `jawab` array.

Not only this your `for` loop runs for `i<=31;`, you index `i` in loop `kunci[i]` for i > 19 that is another point of array out of index bug. -- Just declare arrays large enough to rectify both mistakes.